# Grunt compile all .less to .css in each directory

Tags: gruntjs, less, grunt-contrib-watch, grunt-contrib-less

So I have setup my site to use modules, in which each module has it's own .less file which needs to be compiled into .css.

Folder Structure: 
`/common/modules/{module-name}/style.less`

I need all the style.less files to be converted into style.css files in the same directory. For example:

`/common/modules/clock/style.less` would need to be compiled to `/common/modules/clock/style.css`

I don't want to have to add each of the modules individually to my grunt file, is there a way to do this dynamically?

Answer (score 4):

See also: http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns

You can define the following task:

```
  grunt.initConfig({
    less: {
      compileCore: {
        options: {
          strictMath: true
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          src: ['/common/modules/**/style.less'], 
          ext: '.css',
          extDot: 'first'
        }]
      }
  }
  });
```