# Grunt watch less files in dynamic path

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, less, grunt-contrib-less

Good day!

As I can configure grunt to monitor a dynamic path, I explain, I have a path `(/module/[namemodule]/assets/*.less)`, in the `namemodule` part it changes, it can be anything (name) how can I have the assets folder of all the modules monitored ?, now, the destination will also change, it will not be in assets, it will be public `(/module/[namemodule]/public/*.css)`, the truth is that it is the first time I use grunt and I'm lost

---

Thanks for replying, I have this in my gruntfile.js...

```
less: {
    developmen: {
        options: {
            compress: true,
            yuicompress: true,
            optimization: 2
        },
        files: {
            "/modules/**/public/*.css": "/modules/**/assets/*.less"
        }
    }
}
```

and even then you can not compile the file less, grunt returns the following message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grunt compile all .less to .css in each directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26106254/grunt-compile-all-less-to-css-in-each-directory)

Answer (score 1):

Please see [Globbing Patterns](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns).

Double splat `**` should do what you need.

**UPDATE** Not a valid key value pair methinks

```
    files: {
        "/modules/**/public/*.css": "/modules/**/assets/*.less"
    }
```

Try using an absolute path for the first argument and see what happens.